# Angular / Spring Boot - Additional character in HTTP body

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm using angular-cli with Angular 4 to develop a little application with Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE backend.

When I use `http.post` the server receives HTTP bodies with an additional character (`]`) which leads to deserialization exceptions. Chrome developer tools shows request without it. Other HTTP request methods are not used until now.

What my Spring Boot backend gets with a HTTP POST is something like:

```
{
  "id": "1111",
  "customer": "acustomer",
  "date": "1950-01-01",
  "duration": "0"
}]
```

What it should be:

```
{
  "id": "1111",
  "customer": "acustomer",
  "date": "1950-01-01",
  "duration": "0"
}
```

First thing I tried is to send my entity by using `JSON.stringify(...)` but the addition `]` was there, too.

```
this.http.post('/api/work', JSON.stringify(entity))...
```

Second thought was that the proxy adds it. For development propose I configured a proxy via *proxy.conf.json* file. When I build the application with `ng build` and serve it from Spring Boot server the same issue occurred.

proxy.conf.json

`{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
}`

When I use HTTP GET in Angular 4 every GET request has a body with a single `]`.

I search for a while with Google but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't in the Angular 2 code which I focused too much. It's in my Java code, where I used the annotation `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody`.

The logger still shows the additional `]` but no deserialization exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not having a problem on frontend, since you dont see any problem in the data in Developer tool.
Try adding `consumes` property to `RequestMapping` of your controller:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/something", headers = "content-type="application/json", consumes = "application/json")`

This should trim that character

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Your ideas are not the solution but the lead me to the issue which was in my Java code.

Comment: No problem. What was the problem, if you don't mind sharing that?

Comment: I wrote my solution as separate answer.